# for each text between two strings VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get all text between 2 static strings in Visual Basic.
For example:

```
Hello my name is Jesse Hello ........ Hello my name is John Hello ...... Hello my name is Frank Hello ........
```

I want to search between Hello my name is and Hello so the output will be:

```
Jesse
John
Frank
```

I've done some research on this but I only could find how to get it with 1 outcome and I hope someone here can help me.

I currently have

```
Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim i As Integer = s.IndexOf("Hello my name is")
Dim result As String = s.Substring(i + 1, s.IndexOf("Hello", i + 1) - i - 1)
```

But it wil only give 1 output.

Thanks.

Comment: please post some code

Comment: editted the main post @Paolo

Comment: Is the "Hello ........." part the second "static string" that should be removed?

Comment: Only the Hello is static all after is just random @Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions.
You need to use Regular expressions, i.e. System.Text.RegularExpressions

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(TextBox1.Text, "Hello my name is (\w+)")
For Each m As Match In matches
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1).Value)
Next
```

If you're new to regular expressions then I can only give you a warm hug and say, "I'm sorry."

Comment: Im sorry but I am new to this all and I dont know how to get it working. I am learning thats why I am here :) and unfortunately I cant get your code working.

Comment: Hi Jesse, I've added in the code for looping over the matches. Now, regular expressions are powerful magic and very useful for string manipulation. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, for a given `input` string:

```
ReadOnly Separators As String() = { "Hello my name is " }
Dim names As String() = input _
    .Split(Separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) _
    .Where(Function(s) Not s.StartsWith("Hello")) _
    .ToArray()

For Each name As String In names
    Console.WriteLine(name)
Next
```

This:

1. Splits the string in multiple strings and removes the static "Hello my name is " string parts from the input.
2. Filters this with the `Where`, to exclude any string starting with "Hello"
3. Converts the result to an array using `ToArray`

Comment: Thanks but this will give everything after Hello my name is which means I get Jesse Hello ......, John Hello......, and Frank Hello......

Comment: @Jesse That is why I asked you if the "Hello ......" should also be removed. Your answer to that was not "yes". I have updated the answer to also remove the "Hello .....".

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. I tried the code and I think it is almost done. Just one question. Is it possible to delete like everything after the second Hello? Because what I meant in my comment was that it could be Hello my name is Jesse Hello *random text here* Hello my name is John Hello *Some other random text*. So it would like delete everything after the second Hello untill it finds a new "Hello my name is" and he will get the name and do it over and over.

Comment: Thanks @Alex I changed it but it seems that I get somme errors. I will post a gyazo [click here](http://gyazo.com/805c0602850ae50505ae11f3416f6cc6) also I changed the ReadOnly to Dim.

Comment: @Jesse I forgot that VB needs `_` if you split a statement over multiple lines. Fixed

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue. The answer from @Leon Bambrick also worked. Thanks for the effort.